# Render multiple photoshop layers to file automatically. With a twist

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, automation

I have a question about automating my workflow. I have a photoshop file that consists of a Base Layer with some content that will always be visible. I also have a second category of about 15 layers that i wish to render on top of that base layer. Now I would like to achieve two things. 
Firstly I would like to automate the rendering so that it will save 15 (strictly speaking 16) versions of that file with Base layer + one of the layers in the second category (including the version with just the base layer strictly speaking). 
Secondly I would like to render all versions in all combinations. I.e All combinations with Base Layer + 2 layers of the second category, all combinations with Base Layer + 3 layers of the second category and so on. 
Is this already a scripting job or is there an easier way to achieve this? 
Best regards Roxi

Comment: I think you would probably have to write a script for this. Perhaps you could record an Action, enabling certain layers, and saving, etc. But an Action wouldn't be much use unless you had lots of separate files with the exact same structure and layer names to process. To be honest, if this is for just one file, you might be quicker just doing it manually.  The time taken to write a script and test it may be longer.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using layer comps in Photoshop and export via export layer comps.

You may find it laborious to set up at first but you can make a layer comps and on that layer specify what layers are turned on an off.

I would advise caution though. After several layers it can easily get confusing what layer contains what, so my advise for you is to use a logical naming convention that ties back to the layers and makes it easy for you to keep track.

For example, I have a .psd file with a layer called **Base layer 1** and then **Artwork layer 1**, **Artwork layer 2** etc up 15.

For my layer comps I may called them **Base layer 1 + Artwork Layer 1**, then **Base Layer 1 + Artwork layer 2**. This way after a lot of layer comps in different combinations are made I can keep track of their set up and match them up to artwork layers.

One last point. On layer comps you can toggle visibility, position, and appearance. If they are turned on it will remember them. If they are are turn off it wont, and you could easily end up with a lot of layers that are not remembering which layers need to be on ir off.

Comment: Combining the base layer with up to 3 other layers will give [455 combinations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=combinations%5B%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%7D%2C%7B3%7D%5D). That's a lot to set up manually. And the OP wants "and so on"!

Comment: You make a very reasonable point Wolff.